# Getting data from API

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

```
function() {
  var questions = [{
    question: "What is 1*5?",
    choices: [2, 5, 10, 15],
    correctAnswer: 1
  }, {
    question: "What is 2*3?",
    choices: [3, 6, 9, 12],
    correctAnswer: 1
  }, {
    question: "What is 6-3?",
    choices: [2, 9, 8, 3],
    correctAnswer: 3
  }, {
    question: "What is 1*4?",
    choices: [4, 5, 6, 7],
    correctAnswer: 0
  }, {
    question: "What is 6*7?",
    choices: [20, 30, 42, 50],
    correctAnswer: 2
  }];
}
```

Here is my code now I want to get this data from api rather than adding randomly so kindly help as am new to json data concepts.

Comment: Was is your concrete question?

Comment: What have you tried? And what did or didn't work about that?

Comment: JSON is a string not much to know there. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have no idea what your question is

Comment: Do you already have an API that returns this data?

Comment: what API is that then? Have you got one? Are you asking how to build an API? How to connect? It's not clear at all what your problem is.